# List of Valid Operations for Mark-for-Op in Cloud Custodian

Tags: cloudcustodian

I was wondering what were some valid operations that we can do for mark-for-op in cloud custodian. I know pause and stop are valid operations. However, I am running this on my company's subscription and I would just like to see all my options before I pause a possible resource that could be important to the company.

```yaml
- type: mark-for-op
  tag: c7n_ni_not_allowed
  op:
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `mark-for-op` will allow the `op` key to work with any `action` that corresponds to the `resource`.

For example, see the policy on [this page](https://github.com/cloud-custodian/cloud-custodian/blob/002fa72de3cb3faf6309b0608a4f4216c2f1d571/docs/source/azure/examples/resourcegroupsdelayedoperation-general.rst) copied below.

```yaml
policies:
  - name: rg-mark-empty-for-deletion
    description: |
      Find any empty resource groups and mark for deletion in 7 days
    resource: azure.resourcegroup
    filters:
      - "tag:c7n_rg_empty": absent
      - type: empty-group
    actions:
      - type: mark-for-op
        tag: c7n_rg_empty
        op: delete
        days: 7
```

This will do the operation `delete` on the resource `azure.resourcegroup`. This operation is shown under the [actions](https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/azure/resources/resourcegroup.html#actions) section of the corresponding resource.

Perhaps a better name for the `op` key is `action`?